# Text inside InkWell with overflow applied not working flutter

Tags: flutter, row

A simple code like one below fails on TextOverflow - replace with very long text for "searchLocationAddress". Flutter 1.17.5. All provided solutions - Flexible, Expandable, etc fail. Troubleshooting narrows down to InkWell, if InkWell is removed, the elipsis, fade etc work. If you replace with GestureDetector, the same problem like for InkWell occurs - TextOverFlow is not applied. What is the best way to wrap a text to detect a tap and action and still apply the OverFlow?

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => _navigateAndDisplaySelection(),
              child: Text(
                searchLocationAddress.isEmpty ||
                        searchLocationAddress == null
                    ? "No Location"
                    : searchLocationAddress,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Your width is dynamic. Have you tried setting a width to your row, container or column so that inkwell overflow boundaries can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out - the best is to wrap the InkWell or GestureDector with Container and the Expanded or Flexible. The below worked for me:

```
Column(
children: <Widget>[
  Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(Wrap Container with Flexible or Expanded.
                      child: Container(//wrap InkWell with Container
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => _navigateAndDisplaySelection(),
              child: Text(
                searchLocationAddress.isEmpty ||
                        searchLocationAddress == null
                    ? "No Location"
                    : searchLocationAddress,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
],
);
```